# How to display tab numbers

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to display the tab number in the tab bar?

I enjoy using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> etc. to switch between open tabs, however it can get taxing to have to count out the tabs (for me anyway). It would be nice if the tabs had numbers.

Comment: 2 years later :) any progress on this ?

Comment: 3.5 years later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to write a plugin for it but there is no such standard feature, as of the latest version, Build 3083, in ST3.

Edit: I would recommend using https://github.com/travmik/ZenTabs to easily manage tabs

Comment: Thanks for the plugin suggestion, I'll definitely take a look.

Comment: I figured I would try to roll my own plugin but it turns out the API is broken (in my opinion anyway). There's a `set_name()` method on the `view` object which changes the tab name but it also changes the underlying file association, so when you try to save the file you get the "save as" dialog. ...Oh well it was worth a shot.

Comment: I agree with you that the separation between the model and the view is not done right in the API if that is the case. Hopefully they will change it soon, the pace of development and new features has been quite slow in 2014 but lately it seems like they are improving on that.